# JPA composite foreign key to multiple tables (no inheritance)

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have to deal with a poorly normalised and schema that doesn't follow any of the good practices and I need to integrate it with JPA. Changing the schema is not an option...

Basically I have the following schema in a simplified way:

```
Table - PhoneNumber
- INT: id
- CHAR: type (C, P, S, A)
- VARCHAR: fk
...

Table - Customer
- VARCHAR: id
- VARCHAR: name
...

Table - Provider
- VARCHAR: id
- VARCHAR: name
...

Table - Contact
- INT: id
- VARCHAR: name
...
```

The Type value can be either C, S, P, or A and depending on this value the 'FK' colum id will mean that it's Provider, Customer, or other entities. The type of the ID is converted to string if it's a numeric value.

How can I create an entity that looks like this?

```
@Entity
public class PhoneNumber {
    @Id Integer id;
    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    //Some way to discrimine based on TYPE column = 'C'
    Customer customer;
    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    //Some way to discrimine based on TYPE column = 'P'
    Provider provider;
    ...
}
```

So far the problem is solved creating some transient fields and fetching manually the entities but I'd like to refactor it in cleaner way.

Answer (score 1):

If you're fine with having a single field for all the related entities, have a look at [`@Any`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Any.html).

Otherwise, you could try using [`@JoinColumnOrFormulas`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/JoinColumnsOrFormulas.html) (with sth like `@JoinColumn(name = "fk")` and `@JoinFormula(value = "'C'", referencedColumnName = "type")` for `Customer`, for instance). Not entirely sure `@JoinFormula` will work this way, though.

Finally, a vanilla JPA solution would be to create a single-table inheritance hierarchy with separate entities for `CustomerPhone`, `ProviderPhone` etc., with `type` being the discriminator column.